# Asp.net: How can i display API result in a view

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api

How can i display Json data in asp.net view? I used the following API and used `GroupBy` to group data by ID

I have this code to generate the json result shown below

```
[HttpGet("{ID}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompanyByID(int produtID)
{
    var company= await companyListService.GetCompanyByID(productID); 
    var companyList= company.GroupBy(x => x.ID);
    return Ok(companyList);
}
```

My json result after grouping

```
[
 { "ID": 13,
   "CompName": "MULETA PLC ",
   "ContractorName": "ENGINEERING" 
 }, 
 { "ID": 13,
   "CompName": "MULETA PLC ",
   "ContractorName": "SUNS CONST." 
 }
]
```

Before grouping the result using `var companyList= company.GroupBy(x => x.ID);` I had the following code in my view and was working fine.

In my View i have this:

```
@inject ICompanyService companyListService @{
    var ProductID = Model.ID;
    var compInfo = await companyListService.GetCompanyByID(ProductID); 
}
```

To create a list i used  this code

```
<ul id="list" style="line-height: 0.01;">
    @foreach (var item in compInfo)
    {
        <li data-id="@item.ID">@item.CompanyName                             
            <ul>
                <li data-expanded="true" data-id="@subcontractor.ID">@scontractor.ContractorName</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

How can i modify the above `foreach` to get the following list

- MULETA PLC

  - YIBA ENGINEERING
  - SUNS CONST.
- MULETA PLC

  - YIBA ENGINEERING
  - SUNS CONST.

Comment: Hi @Edward Thanks you!  i tried that but doesnt work for me

Comment: I could be wrong on this statement, but I thought calls to the DB are back end code, as in should be in the controller not the views

Comment: @item.CompName was working but i modify the API  by adding `var companyList= company.GroupBy(x => x.ID);`  now its not working, do i have to modify the foreach?

Comment: Put a break on that line and see what the object has in it.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
public class OutputClass
{
   public List<InnerClass> Companies{ get; set; }
}

public class InnerClass
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string CompName { get; set; }
  public string ContractorName { get; set; }
}

//return a list type of InnerClass that is used in grouping in next line
var company= await companyListService.GetCompanyByID(productID); 
var companyList= company.GroupBy(x => x.ID).Select(grp => new OutputClass
                                            {
                                                Companies = grp.ToList()
                                            }).ToList();
    return Ok(companyList);
```

result will be

```
{
   "companies":[
      [
         {
            "ID":13,
            "CompName":"MULETA PLC ",
            "ContractorName":"ENGINEERING"
         },
         {
            "ID":13,
            "CompName":"MULETA PLC ",
            "ContractorName":"SUNS CONST."
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

I have created a class with list of companies inside it which will allow us to iterate through after grouping.
First loop = companiesList.companies;
Second loop = companies. Where we can actually access the properties

```
@foreach(var companies in companyList)
{
  @foreach(var company in companies)
  {
    <p>@company.ID</p>
    <p>@company.CompName</p>
    <p>@company.ContractorName</p>

  } 
}
```

Comment: Lasanga Guruge Thanks! It works i am able to display them in a view but doesn't group them by compName in a view

Comment: Currently grouped by the ID if you want to groub by name then instead of id in groubBy linq method use compName

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically, your class structure for this is not well formed, So, I would recommend you to break your classes so you can show the data in the desired way, for example:

```
public class Company
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CompName { get; set; }
    public List<Contractor> Contractors { get; set; }
    // Your Other Properties
}

public class Contractor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ContractorName { get; set; }
    // Your Other Properties
}
```

This way, the JSON you return would be like below:

```
[
 { 
   "ID": 13,
   "CompName": "MULETA PLC ",
   "Contractors": [
     {
          "ID": 1,
          "ContractorName" : "ENGINEERING",
     },
     {
          "ID": 2,
          "ContractorName" : "SUNS CONST."
     }
   ] 
 },
 { 
   "ID": 14,
   "CompName": "Hello, World!",
   "Contractors": [
     {
          "ID": 3,
          "ContractorName" : "Hello"
     },
     {
          "ID": 4,
          "ContractorName" : "World"
     }
    ] 
  }
]
```

After that you can easily display the list like you wanted, see:

```
<ul id="list" style="line-height: 0.01;">
    @foreach (var item in compInfo)
    {
        <li data-id="@item.ID">
            @item.CompanyName                             
            <ul>
                @foreach (var contractor in item.Contractors) 
                {
                    <li data-expanded="true" data-id="@contractor.ID">@contractor.ContractorName</li>
                }
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Can i create the class structure like that for a single table? Its Just one table

Comment: Either you might want to split the tables with primary/foreign key references or you can make the classes and structure the JSON with that class.

Comment: Thanks Jamshaid! Can i select distinct in the first `foreach` `@foreach (var item in compInfo)`?

Comment: @Rob, You can do anything you want but that will depend on what you want the output to be. Now, the question is Why would you do that if the data is well organized and you are not having duplicates in the first place?

Comment: Yes, your suggested structure is exactly what i was looking for unfortunately i am using Views as an Entity and  the foreach is repeat CompanyName i was thinking for the first `foreach` to select distinct companyName and display all contractors under

Comment: I tried select distinct as `@foreach (var item in compInfo.Select(x => x.CompName).Distinct())` but tthat gives me error `cannot use lambda expression argument dynamically dispatched`

Comment: @Rob, That error means you are not getting a list in the `foreach` to iterate through, it is an `IQueryable`. Try putting a `.ToList();` at the end of the `Distinct()` method.

Comment: Selecting Distinct is not going to help I think. It will help you if you structure your tables, it would be helpful to overcome the data redundancy as well as it would make a proper object in your case.